# What would be the function for this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A cell phone plan has $700$ minutes of talking for $20$ dollars with each additional minute over $700$ minutes costing $10$ cents per minute.

I had $f(x)=0.1t-50$ but then I plugged in $0$ and got $-50$ which is wrong.

I'm pretty confused right now.

Comment: Is it a flat fee for the first 700 minutes (i.e., is the fee to sign up simply 700 outright)? Also, your function will clearly be a function of $t$, not $x$, as it is currently written.

Comment: Yes it is flat.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most concise version of your function will be
$$
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
20 & \text{if $0<t\leq 700$},\\
20 + 0.1(\lceil t\rceil - 700) & \text{if $t>700$}.
\end{cases}
$$
Does that make sense?

*Note:* The notation $\lceil t\rceil$ stands for the [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Answer (score 0):

It's a conditional function:

t = minutes in whole minutes.

f(t) = 20 if t <= 700;

f(t) = .1*t - 50;  if t > 700

======

If you want to get technical.  Let floor(t) = the largest integer equal or less than t.  (This is a stepwise non-continuous function).

f(t) = 20 if t<=700.

f(t) = .1*floor(t) - 50; if t > 700.

Comment: Are you sure it's a linear function? The cost per minute probably doesn't vary per second.

Comment: No, it isn't a linear function.

Comment: A cell phone plan has 700 minutes of talking for 20 dollars with each additional minute over 700 minutes costing 10 cents per minute. Write a function representing this rate for any positive time t. Then graph the function between 0 and 1000.


I'm using Julia with Gadfly package. I'm not sure if you know what that is but it says IF not defined. Any clue on that?

Comment: Any clue on what?

Comment: http://puu.sh/kGuUb/03425b6294.png

Comment: You don't have to use a piecewise function

Comment: Oh, for eff sake.  You asked a *math* question.  Translating the math question into proper computer code is up to you.  You can't just cut and paste.  I don't know how to do and IF clause in Julia with Gadfly..... Okay, deep breath... I'd suggest putting it into and IF (t > 700){ } ELSE {  } type clause.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee   Why don't I let you and Daniel Farlow fight it out.  You do need piecewise if you are concerned about fractions of minutes.  Which I wouldn't be.

Comment: @fleablood You still don't need piecewise - use a ceiling function for the fractional minutes...

Comment: Um, a ceilig function *is* piecewise.  (Also, wouldn't it be a floor function).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [piecewise-defined function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise). Or you could be cooler and use only one equation:

$$f(x) = \frac{\lceil x\rceil +\left|\lceil x \rceil -700\right|}{20}-15$$

This uses the [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) for rounding up to the minute. The vertical bars denote [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).

Comment: I still don't think this works. Are you saying that if someone uses half of minute 701 then it will be cheaper than using the whole minute? It's not a linear function I don't think.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow How about this?

Comment: Amusing--I just wrote up my own little answer while you fixed this one. Yeah, I think the ceiling function does it.

Comment: No, he is saying it will be 1/2 a minute with be the same as using a whole minute.  Do you know what ceiling means.  And stop saying "linear" when you mean continuously increasing.  My interpretation is I'd use floor as I assume 700 minutes and 30 seconds counts as 700 rather than 701 but the question isn't that clear.  This is an elegant single phrase function that avoids my conditional, which is pretty cool.  Nice answer.